# Multiple IF/And as array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am attempting to create an array that will compare the contents of two cells and return a resultant text to a third cell. I am able to make it work as a formula in a single cell, but when I attempt to make it an array, I get parse errors.

The formula that works on a single row is:

`=IF(AND(F3="Female",H3<1),"pink",IF(AND(F3="Female",H3>1),"red",IF(AND(F3="Male",H3<1),"blue",IF(AND(F3="Male",H3>1),"green"))))`

I have tried the following two arrays without success:
    `=arrayformula(IF(AND(F3:F="Female",H3:H<1),"pink",IF(AND(F3:F="Female",H3:H>1),"red",IF(AND(F3:F="Male",H3:H<1),"blue",IF(AND(F3:F="Male",H3:H>1),"green")))))`

and
    `=arrayformula(IF(AND($F$3:$F="Female",$H$3:$H<1),"pink",IF(AND($F$3:$F="Female",$H$3:$H>1),"red",IF(AND($F$3:$F="Male",$H$3:$H<1),"blue",IF(AND($F$3:$F="Male",$H$3:$H>1),"green")))))`

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I changed all instances of `AND` to `*` but still get a parse error.  Here is what I tried: `=arrayformula(IF(*(F3:F="Female",H3:H<1),"pink",IF(*(F3:F="Female",H3:H>1),"red",IF(*(F3:F="Male",H3:H<1),"blue",IF(*(F3:F="Male",H3:H>1),"green")))))`

Comment: I didn'r see the example the first time I looked.  I have now tried `=arrayformula(IF(*({F3:F="Female"},{H3:H<1}),"pink",IF(*({F3:F="Female"},{H3:H>1}),"red",IF(*({F3:F="Male"},{H3:H<1}),"blue",IF(*({F3:F="Male"},{H3:H>1}),"green")))))` and `=arrayformula(IF(AND({F3:F="Female"},{H3:H<1}),"pink",IF(AND({F3:F="Female"},{H3:H>1}),"red",IF(AND({F3:F="Male"},{H3:H<1}),"blue",IF(AND({F3:F="Male"},{H3:H>1}),"green")))))` with an error and a `FALSE` return.....at least I got a return, so I'm getting closer

Comment: I tried it with this; `=arrayformula(IF(F3="Female"*H3<1,"pink",IF(F3="Female"*H3>1,"red",IF(F3="Male"*H3<1,"blue",IF(F3="Male"*H3>1),"green"))))` but it is reading the `*` as a multiplier and giving the error message `#VALUE!`

Comment: Your formula have a problem of operator precedence. Use parentheses to ensure the proper calculation order. i.e. instead of  `F3="Female"*H3<1` use `(F3="Female")*(H3<1)`. Apply the same to the other parts of your formula.

Comment: It came to me as i was staring at it.  It's working now with`=arrayformula(IF({F3:F="Female"}*{H3:H<1},"pink",IF({F3:F="Female"}*{H3:H>1},"red",IF({F3:F="Male"}*{H3:H<1},"blue",IF({F3:F="Male"}*{H3:H>1},"green")))))` Thank you so much